# How to fetch revenue reports from Amazon Publisher Services using API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have access to my client's Amazon Publisher Services account. Now my client wants a tool that can fetch revenue reports from APS and store it into the database. But the problem is that I couldn't find any official doc regarding APS reporting API.

I have already tried https://ams.amazon.com/webpublisher/uam/docs/s3-reports.html but there are no request parameters it's just like an essay.